# UserState showing null in onMembersAdded function

Tags: javascript, node.js, botframework, direct-line-botframework, web-chat

I have logic in my `onMembersAdded` function to load the user state and see if `userData.accountNumber` attribute exists. If it does not, a run an `auth` dialog to get the user's account number. If the attribute *does* exist, the welcome message should be displayed without a prompt.

When I test on local, this works fine. But when I test on Azure, I always end up in the `!userData.accountNumber` block. Through checking the console log, I can see that in the `onMembersAdded` function is showing `{}` for the `userData` object. But in `auth` dialog, even if I skip the prompt (which we allow the user to do), the `accountNumber` attribute is there in `userState` (if it had been entered previously).

The only thing I can figure is that somehow using `BlobStorage` for state, as I do on Azure, is somehow exhibiting different behavior than `MemoryStorage` which I am using for local testing. I thought it might be a timing issue, but I am awaiting the get user state call, and besides if I *do* enter an account number in the `auth` dialog, the console log immediately following the prompt shows the updated account number, no problem.

**EDIT:** From the comments below, it's apparent that the issue is the different way channels handle `onMembersAdded`. It seems in emulator both bot and user are added at the same time, but on webchat/directline, user isn't added until the first message is sent. So that is the issue I need a solution to.

Here is the code in the constructor defining the state variables and `onMembersAdded` function:

```js
// Snippet from the constructor. UserState is passed in from index.js

// Create the property accessors
this.userDialogStateAccessor = userState.createProperty(USER_DIALOG_STATE_PROPERTY);
this.dialogState = conversationState.createProperty(DIALOG_STATE_PROPERTY);

// Create local objects
this.conversationState = conversationState;
this.userState = userState;

        this.onMembersAdded(async (context, next) => {
            const membersAdded = context.activity.membersAdded;

            for (let member of membersAdded) {
                if (member.id === context.activity.recipient.id) {
                    this.appInsightsClient.trackEvent({name:'userAdded'});

                    // Get user state. If we don't have the account number, run an authentication dialog
                    // For initial release this is a simple prompt
                    const userData = await this.userDialogStateAccessor.get(context, {});
                    console.log('Members added flow');
                    console.log(userData);
                    if (!userData.accountNumber) {
                        console.log('In !userData.accountNumber block');
                        const dc = await this.dialogs.createContext(context);
                        await dc.beginDialog(AUTH_DIALOG);
                        await this.conversationState.saveChanges(context);
                        await this.userState.saveChanges(context);
                    } else {
                        console.log('In userData.accountNumber block');
                        var welcomeCard = CardHelper.GetHeroCard('',welcomeMessage,menuOptions);
                        await context.sendActivity(welcomeCard);
                        this.appInsightsClient.trackEvent({name:'conversationStart', properties:{accountNumber:userData.accountNumber}});
                    }
                }
            }

            // By calling next() you ensure that the next BotHandler is run.
            await next();
        });
```

Comment: Have you tried using blob storage during local testing?

Comment: Unfortunately I've not been able to get Blob Storage for state working through my corporate proxy. I get StorageError: Forbidden (storage account name and key have been verified as correct). Blob does work fine on Azure...except for this onMembersAdded issue.

Comment: What channel are you using?

Comment: Right now I can only test with OOTB webchat channel. Eventually we will use DirectLine (via botframework-webchat CDN) but as of yet we don't have a working method to save userID across multiple sessions. So for now I want to get this working in OOTB webchat channel as in local, but solution will need to work for DirectLine as well.

Comment: Have you tried using a backchannel join event instead of relying on a conversation update activity? https://github.com/microsoft/BotFramework-WebChat/tree/master/samples/04.api/a.welcome-event

Comment: While primary channel will be webchat, that doesn't help when we're using other channels like Teams. The issue isn't onMembersAdded not working, it's the fact that I'm not getting the data stored in userState within that function.

Comment: So you're not just targeting Direct Line? Anyway, this probably has to do with Web Chat not including the correct user ID when it sends the conversation update to your bot. This can be related to the way the Direct Line token is generated. It would help to see your front-end code.

Comment: Okay it looks like when you say OOTB webchat you mean the embed URL. I don't think you're going to be able to control the user ID for that. To verify that the user ID is indeed the problem here, you can log `context.activity.from.id` the same way you're logging the user data. You can also check the bot state to make sure it contains an entry for that user ID by inspecting the storage resource in Azure or by using inspection middleware.

Comment: Sorry, I was wrong. It looks like you can [pass a token](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/bot-service/bot-service-channel-connect-webchat?view=azure-bot-service-4.0#option-1---exchange-your-secret-for-a-token-and-generate-the-embed) to the embed URL instead of your secret, and you can specify a user ID when you generate the token. As an aside, if you want to keep your secret a secret then you might want to delete your comment here that contains it.

Comment: I can confirm that with embed URL and directline webchat, user ID is remembered and state is retrieved. I just am not getting state in the onMembersAdded function for those channels, whereas it works fine in emulator.

Comment: onMembersAdded is called in response to a conversation update activity. This is channel-specific so you should not expect the same behavior across different channels. In the case of Web Chat, you should expect the conversation update to occur when a conversation is created, which itself happens when a token is generated. It stands to reason that whatever you're experiencing in onMembersAdded is related to how the token is generated. Regardless of what you're seeing on other turns, have you tried logging the user ID in onMembersAdded  like you've logged the user state?

Comment: You're right. On emulator the bot and user are added immediately. On embed and directline webchat the bot is added first and user isn't added until after first activity. So since user isn't added yet, user state can't be retrieved. Given that I'm using the old core-bot as a template (with no root dialog, just a bot file that extends ActivityHandler and chooses action based on LUIS result), what can I do to implement this prompt on welcome?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want your bot to receive a conversation update from Web Chat with the correct user ID before the user sends a message manually, you have two options:

1. Instead of connecting to Direct Line with a secret, connect with a token (recommended). Note that this will only work if you provide a `user` property in the body of your [Generate Token](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/bot-service/rest-api/bot-framework-rest-direct-line-3-0-authentication) request.
2. Have Web Chat send an initial activity to the bot automatically so the user doesn't have to. This would be in response to `DIRECT_LINE/CONNECT_FULFILLED`, and it could be an invisible event activity so to the user it still looks like the first activity in the conversation came from the bot.

If you go with option 1, your bot will receive one conversation update with both the bot and the user in `membersAdded`, and the from ID of the activity will be the user ID. This is ideal because it means you will be able to acess user state.

If you go with option 2, your bot will receive two conversation update activities. The first is the one you're receiving now, and the second is the one with the user ID that you need. The funny thing about that first conversation update is that the from ID is the conversation ID rather than the bot ID. I presume this was an attempt on Web Chat's part to get the bot to mistake it for the user being added, since Bot Framework bots typically recognize that conversation update by checking if the from ID is different from the member being added. Unfortunately this can result in two welcome messages being sent because it's harder to tell which conversation update to respond to.

Conversation updates have been historically unreliable in Web Chat, as evidenced by [a series of GitHub issues](https://github.com/microsoft/BotFramework-WebChat/issues/1728). Since you may end up having to write channel-aware bot code anyway, you might consider having the bot respond to a [backchannel event](https://github.com/microsoft/BotFramework-WebChat/tree/master/samples/04.api/a.welcome-event) instead of a conversation update when it detects that the channel is Web Chat. This is similar to option 2 but you'd have your bot actually respond to that event rather than the conversation update that got sent because of the event.

Comment: I have been meaning to investigate connecting with token anyway, so I will try option 1 and see if that solves the issue with getting state on welcome, which from your explanation I suspect it will.

Comment: I got a solution working, but it wasn't easy. I'm accepting your answer but I will also provide an additional answer with code on how to actually implement this, because the token documentation isn't entirely clear to me.

Answer (score 1):

Per Kyle's answer, I was able to resolve the issue. However, the documentation on initiating a chat session via tokens wasn't entirely clear, so I wanted to provide some guidance for others trying to solve this same issue.

First, you need to create an endpoint in your bot to generate the token. The reason I initiated the session from SECRET initially was because I didn't see a point to creating a token when the SECRET was exposed anyway to generate it. What wasn't made clear in the documentation was that you should create a separate endpoint so that the SECRET isn't in the browser code. You can/should further obfuscate the SECRET using environmental variables or key vault. Here is the code for the endpoint I set up (I'm passing in userId from browser, which you'll see in a minute).

```js
server.post('/directline/token', async (req, res) => {

    try {
        var body = {User:{Id:req.body.userId}};
        const response = await request({
            url: 'https://directline.botframework.com/v3/directline/tokens/generate',
            method: 'POST',
            headers: { Authorization: `Bearer ${process.env.DIRECTLINE_SECRET}`},
            json: body,
            rejectUnauthorized: false
        });
        const token = response.token;
        res.setHeader('Content-Type', 'text/plain');
        res.writeHead(200);
        res.write(token);
        res.end();
    } catch(err) {
        console.log(err);
        res.setHeader('Content-Type', 'text/plain');
        res.writeHead(500);
        res.write('Call to retrieve token from Direct Line failed');
        res.end();
    }
})
```

You could return JSON here, but I chose to return token only as text. Now to call the function, you'll need to hit this endpoint from the script wherever you are deploying the bot (this is assuming you are using botframework-webchat CDN). Here is the code I used for that.

```js
    const response = await fetch('https://YOURAPPSERVICE.azurewebsites.net/directline/token', {
        method: 'POST',
        headers: {'Content-Type':'application/json'},
        body: JSON.stringify({userId:userID})
    });
    const token = await response.text();
```

Body of request must be stringified JSON. `Fetch` returns the response as a stream, so you need to convert it using `.text()` or `.json()` depending on how you are sending the response from your bot endpoint (I used `.text()`). You need to await both the `fetch` *AND* the `response.text()`. My whole script to deploy the webchat is within an async function. Just a note, if you need this to work in IE11 as I do, async/await won't work. I dealt with this by running the entire code through Babel once I was done and it seems to work fine.

Comment: Sorry about the documentation being light. I believe a token generation sample is being worked on now.